# Escaping an apostrophe in a character literal

Tags: c++, escaping

Could you please tell me how can one escape an apostrophe.

I need it to process non apostrophe characters through file operations so when I encounter an apostrophe(`'`) I can't just give `ch!='''`. It doesn't work. Could you please tell me the right format. Thank you..:)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `\'`, for example:

```
if ( ch != '\'' )
```

`\'` is an escape sequence for the apostrophe.

Google for "escape sequence" to know more about it.

Comment: Hi..:) thank you for your answer.. Just saw ur blog.. even I am from ase, ase-bang

Answer (score 14):

You can **escape** a single quote as

```
'\''
```

for example

```
while(*p && *p != '\'') p++;
```

This is an [escape sequence](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/escape_sequences); the backslash tells the compiler that following `'` normal character, and not as one of the single quotes that you surround a character with.

Comment: *"next character is to be treated as a normal character"* ... that could be read as `\0` becoming `0` and ignores octal and hex numbers.

Comment: Right, but I'm talking about the specific escape sequence `\'` ... I'm not trying to imply that all escape sequences are a given length.

Comment: Thought so, just wanted to point out the possible misunderstanding.