# How do I treat ' like a normal letter

Tags: c, compiler-errors, syntax-error, character

```
else if (isspace(text[i]) || (text[i]) == ')
{
    words++;
}
```

In the terminal it says: "error: missing terminating ' character [-Werror,-Winvalid-pp-token]".

Comment: Because that's not a valid char literal. Try `'\''`.

Answer (score 2):

Single characters are denoted by single quotes (`'`) surrounding them, even the `'` character itself - although you'd need to escape it with a backslash (`\`):

```c
else if (isspace(text[i]) || (text[i]) == '\'')
{
    words++;
}
```

Comment: You're correct.  But this question was asked - and answered - 11 years ago.  Hence [Closed/Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414478/)

Comment: @paulsm4: You’re correct. But the fact that this was asked and answered 11 years ago and hence was closed as a duplicate is shown by Stack Overflow at the top of the page.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: I know that.  Mureinik, SuperStormer and I all noticed the question about the same time.  It's a legitimate newbie question.  I don't know if Mureinik replied before or after it was closed (probably "before"). But SuperStormer did the right thing ("closed duplicate", with a brief, explanatory comment to the OP).  I just wanted to remind Mureinik that's what he should have done.  With 259k rep, he probably should have known better...